# Shall I use `*` to chown all the files in one folder faster?

Tags: linux, ssh, chown

I have 50+ scripts in folder `cron-scripts`, I only want exec them with cron shell only by root privileges.

```
# cd /var/www/html/cron-scripts/
# chown root:root scripts1.php
# chown fishman:users scripts1.php
# chown root:root scripts2.php
# chown fishman:users scripts2.php
```

Shall I use `*` to instead above code with the same effect?

```
# cd /var/www/html/cron-scripts/
# chown root:root *
# chown fishman:users *
```

And how to remove the root privileges if I have made `chown root:root other-script.php`?

I mean I want make this script open to all the public. (chown all-users:users other-script.php) thanks.

Comment: You could have the cron job use `super` or `sudo` to give root priviledges. Remember that running as `root` is always a security risk.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If you want everybody to be able to run the scripts, make them world-readable and world-executable (`chmod a+rx *), the owner is irrelevant. If you want to run the scripts as root, invoke them from root's crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a file readable by "others", you better use `chmod` with the parameters `o+r` which means "add read access for anyone else".

```
chmod o+r foo.bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to apply `chown` to all files in a directory, you can use the recursive option `chown -R user:group directory`, instead of `*`